# all requests from my machine on ec2 have the same static ip's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My machine is configured in ubuntu. It has a python flask service. I use a domain that I bought with a certificate that I generated at aws.

I am concerned about the security of my service and wanted to use a tool called flask ip ban. However the IP I receive from users both on the console and in the code using '' request.remote_addr '' are specific ip's of the same domain that starts with 172.31. *. *

Even if I use proxies the ip of my pc is always 172.31.4.145 and this is neither my ip nor my proxies.

I tried to use the ip ban flask but I ended up banning literally all users, because those few ip's that seem to bring my clients, without me knowing how, were banned

I would like to know how to do to show the real ip's. Could it be because my service is micro? Or because am I using Load balancer with my certificate? I couldn't get any relationship with flask or python

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Is `172.31.4.145` part of your VPC's CIDR block?

Comment: I am using. idk what is vpc cidr?

Comment: VPC CIDR is the list/range of internal, private IP addresses that your AWS Virtual Private Cloud is configured to use.

Comment: 172.31 is my IPv4 CIDR

Comment: You need to check the `x-forwarded-for` header in the request from the load balancers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are behind a load balancer which mean the IP address you are seeing is the one from your load balancer. As Mark advise above you can use the `x-forwarded-for` header but what I wanted to add is that you have a wonderful blog post that explain it all.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/?nc1=h_ls